# How to share posts on Facebook and deep link to my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, deep-linking

I'm trying to implement deep linking in my iOS app, so far I can post to my wall but only posts that are really links that goes to google.com (obviously this is a test link). I want the user to be navigated to my app when clicking on the post through the Facebook app, please I need a step by step guide cause Facebook documentation about its a little bit complicated. Here's my code:

```
- (void)shareOnFacebookWithName:(NSString *)contentTitle withDescription:(NSString *)contentDescription withLink:(NSString *)contentURL withPictureLink:(NSString *)imageURL andViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController{

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:contentURL];
content.contentTitle = contentTitle;
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
content.contentDescription = contentDescription;

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:viewController
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:self];



}
```

Comment: Did you try posting your app URL scheme as the url link ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492731/generate-a-facebook-link-to-a-specific-object-in-app/37492940#37492940

Comment: Thank you for your answers but nothing works like I explained in the post :(